# Design recommendation for Slack bot used by multiple teams

Tags: websocket, bots, slack-api, slack

I am trying to create a Slack bot and I plan to distribute it via Slack apps directory. Now keep my bot's presence available I will have to make use of [rtm.start](https://api.slack.com/methods/rtm.start) API. Now if at any point of time my server fleet has lets say 100,000 (can go up to 100 mn if I start hosting bots) web-sockets connections. I am looking for clean design for my server which should be scalable and most importantly it should be able to keep my bot's presence always available (even during server restarts).

Here is what I was thinking:

- Make duplicate connections to same Slack team from 1+ servers (how? put the OAuth token in a DB and update counter when a connection is made?)
  re-scan all the pre-existing connections and establish the connection again.
- Only restart one server at a time during deployment

But then I am not sure on how to re-establish the WebSocket connection after server restarts. What happens in a network disruption event when all bots go offline, what is the efficient way to re-establish pre-existing connections.

I looked at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414101/how-to-scale-a-slack-bot-to-1000s-of-teams) but unfortunately its not that detailed/helpful

Comment: If the presence appearance in Slack is not mandatory for you, you may want to check out the [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api). It has almost the same functionality (e.g. you can create chat bots), but works with simple HTTP POSTs, so you do not need to manage websocket connections for every bot.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond @ErikKalkoken. I am aware of Events API and was able to create successful prototype with that. However for me presence of bot is super important :(

Answer (score 0):

You can host multiple servers and open the sockets for same teams on
   all replicas(if bot's presence is too critical then go with at least
   three replicas)

now as you are listening slack's RTM events for every channel on
   multiple servers so you have to make sure that every query is replied
   only once so for that you may use any robust message queue to handle
   this

And a single server can handle many WebSockets(tested till 40k on
   Node.js. It can handle much more too, but latency was high with increasing
 connections), but you should consider load balancing your load
 as you will be out of your memory/IO resources once you will get
   numerous simultaneous requests.

So use Load Balancer before your multiple servers replicas and use
   message queue for handling message and deploy replicas one by one so
   you will have connectivity all the time and you can serve queries faster as load is balanced.